# KDE Connect: Can't start media after pause

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kde-connect

I am using Kubuntu. I have upgraded KDE Connect to version 1.3.3 and in my Android mobile, I am using KDE Connect version 1.10.1. Everything works fine (including file transfer). But if I pause a video from mobile or PC it doesn't matter, I can't start it from my phone. The button was grayed out. I have uploaded screenshots:

**Before pause**

[image: before pause]

and

**After pause**

[image: after pause]

**Update:**
How comes that this is marked as not reproducible? I would write that as an answer, but priority is to get this question reopened first.

There is a [bug report](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/21419), which describes that VLC does not notify DBus when the media playback is paused. It seems that [this issue was fixed a month ago](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/commit/388cb0b6464182c8054db6ccf7bc98c723f0aa25), so the fix should roll out in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: I encounter the exact same problem. I ticket has been created ([here](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/21419)) but I have found no solution

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I have uninstalled KDE Connect from my computer and installed GSconnect instead. The problem gone, also I get some more features like controlling computer's volume level.